# If $f : X \rightarrow [ -\infty, +\infty]$ is a measurable function is $\{x : f(x) < \alpha \}$ a measurable set?

Tags: measure-theory, self-learning

If $f : X \rightarrow [ -\infty, +\infty]$ is a measurable function is $\{x : f(x) < \alpha \}$ a measurable set?

Where $\alpha \in \bar{R}$.

It seems to me that it entirely depends on the range of $f$, for instance if the range of $f$ includes $- \infty$ then the set $\{f(x) : f(x) < \alpha \}$ will be of the form $[- \infty, \beta ]$ or $[- \infty, \beta )$, ($\beta \in \bar{R}$) these sets are not open so they do not map back to a measurable set.

But I think I am wrong, why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, by definition. $\{x\mid f(x)<\alpha\}$ is the preimage $f^{-1}([-\infty,\alpha))$, and the definition of $f$ being measurable is that $f^{-1}(A)$ is measureable whenever $A$ is *measurable* (not just when $A$ is open). Since $[-\infty,\alpha)$ is clearly measurable, its preimage must be too.

It doesn't matter that not all of $A$ may be hit by $f$: the preimage of $A$ is still the preimage of $A$, even if it may *also* be the preimage of some other, smaller, set.

Bonus comment: $[-\infty, \alpha)$ is actually open in $\overline{\mathbb R}$!

Extra bonus comment: In the usual case where the $\sigma$-algebra assumed for the codomain of $f$ is the Borel algebra, then it is *sufficient* for $f$ be measurable that the preimage of every open set is measurable. Then, automatically, the preimages of all *other* Borel subsets of $\overline{\mathbb R}$ will also be measurable sets. (This can be proved directly from the definition of Borel set and $\sigma$-algebra).

Comment: Thank you a lot but I am a bit confused, Big Rudin defines a measurable function in this way: "If $X$ is a measurable space, $Y$ is a topological space, and $f$ is a mapping of $X$ into $Y$, then $f$ is said to be measurable provided that $f^{-1}(V)$ is a measurable set in $X$ for every open set $V$ in $Y$" so I imagine I should be able to prove my question using open sets? Thanks to your bonus comment I understand that $[- \infty, \alpha)$ is open, so that is nice, but what about the case $[-\infty, \beta ]$?

Comment: Ok I got why $A$ is also measurable not just open. And I think the case $[-\infty, \beta]$ is not possible because if the range of $f$ were $[-\infty, \beta]$, where $\beta < \alpha$ then f would not be measurable. correct?

Comment: @Monolite: (1) Your book seems to be using a more restricted definition of "measurable" than the one I found at Wikipedia. This other definition is what the "extra bonus comment" covers.

Comment: @Monolite: (2) The preimage of $[-\infty,\alpha)$ is still the preimage of $[-\infty,\alpha)$ even if not all points in $[-\infty,\alpha)$ are hit by the function. It doesn't matter which _other_ sets it might or might not be a preimage of -- just because _one of the things_ it is is the preimage of $[-\infty,\alpha)$ it needs to be measurable.

Comment: @Monolite: (3) Actually, the preimage of $[-\infty,\beta]$ must itself be measurable, because it is the complement of the preimage of $(\beta,\infty]$, and the complement of a measurable set is measurable.

Comment: I think Rudin gives it as a theorem straight after so I cleared that up. In my second comment I mean $f$ would not be a measurable function if it had as range $[-\infty, \beta]$.

Comment: @Monolite: Why don't you think a function with that range can be measurable? For example, if $f(x)=\min(x,\beta)$, then $f$ is perfectly measurable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19813/discussion-between-monolite-and-henning-makholm).